# Is it possible to run automation tests in Jenkins using maven without Testng or Junit?

Tags: maven, jenkins, testing, automated-tests, build-automation

We have created a testing framework as a general java project without using junit or Testng.
Now, we have have converted this project into maven project.
Now, the question is that can we run this project through Jenkins?

Comment: Sure, if you can provide output Jenkins can understand (the jUnit format is well-understood). That said: there is almost never any reason to create a completely-new test framework, and it's almost certain you shouldn't have.

Comment: My question is: How do you test your own framework code? Furthermore what is the advantage of your testing framework in comparison to JUnit Jupiter / JUnit 4 / TestNG / Spock etc. ?